# First image of javascript array doesn't get displayed on canvas

Tags: javascript, symfony, html5-canvas

I've been having a slight problem with Javacript. I have an array of Image sources in my script that I want to display one after the other on user input.

The problem is that when I first click the Start button (document.getElementById("toStart"), to which I give an EventListener), nothing gets displayed on the canvas. However, the changeDisplay() function has been called (the log is there).

Then I input a key, any key, and the iterator variable increments, I get a new log, and this time, the ball image gets displayed. The Ball image being the one at index 0 in my pics array. It displays all of the images one after the other when I input something, but it's always "one off", as in the previous image gets displayed instead of the next one.

Here's my trimmed down test.js Script :

```
//canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("test_canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//gameloop
var gameHasStarted = false;

//Current question number
var iterator = 0;

//The timer for the changeQuestion method
var t2;

//interval between questions
var intervalBetweenQuestions = 3000;

//Images to display
var pics = ['../images/uploads/ball.png', '../images/uploads/img1.jpg', '../images/uploads/img2.jpg', '../images/uploads/img3.jpg'];

//reference to the image slot in the Twig template
var imageTest = document.getElementById('imageTest');


window.onload = function() {

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        //    alert('keydown');
        if(gameHasStarted) {
            checkKeyPressed(event);
        }

    }, false);

};

document.getElementById("toStart").addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    changeDisplay();

    //every X seconds, here 3 -- If the user doesn't input anything, this switchs the questions when the X seconds are up
    t2 = setInterval(changeQuestion, intervalBetweenQuestions);

    gameHasStarted = true;
});


function changeQuestion() {


    if(gameHasStarted){

        if(iterator < pics.length) {

            if(answers[iterator] == null) {
                //No answer has been given
                answers[iterator] = -1;
                alert("no answer given");
            }

            iterator++;

            //cleans the interval for the new questions
            clearInterval(t2);
            t2 = setInterval(changeQuestion, intervalBetweenQuestions);


            changeDisplay();

        } else {
            alert("Finished the test (you timed out at the end)!");
            //redirect at the end
           // window.location.href = Routing.generate('homepage');
        }

    }
}

function checkKeyPressed(e){
    //the key pressed by the user
    var keynum;

    if(window.event) { // IE
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    } else if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
        keynum = e.which;
    }

    if(keynum < 48 || keynum > 90) {
        /** Ignores F5 for example**/
    } else {

        if(iterator < pics.length) {

            //gets the input of the player recorded
            answers[iterator] = keynum;
            changeQuestion();

        } else {
            alert("Finished the test !");
            window.location.href = Routing.generate('homepage');

        }
    }
}


function changeDisplay() {

    //Clears the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //sets the image's source to the one of the current question
    imageTest.src = pics[iterator];

    //Debug
    console.log("Iterator : " + iterator + " and image  " + imageTest.src);

    //Draws the image -- excuse the weird coordinates
    ctx.drawImage(imageTest, 10 + (iterator + 1)*5, 10+(iterator+1)*5);

    return true;
}
```

And my Twig template :

```
{% block  body %}


    <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-md-3"></div>
        <p id="labelTest">Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="offset-md-3"></div>
        <canvas id="test_canvas" width="760" height="520"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="row offset-md-3">

        <button id="toStart">Start</button>

    </div>
    <div style="display:none;">
        <img id="imageTest" src="#"
             width="300" height="227">
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/test.js') }}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

The first debug log, when I press the Start button the first time and the changeDisplay() method gets called is

```
Iterator : 0 and image  http://localhost:8000/images/uploads/ball.png test.js:54:5
```

Which is exactly what I want, and yet no image gets displayed.

Then when I press something and another call to changeDisplay() is made, the message becomes :

```
Iterator : 1 and image  http://localhost:8000/images/uploads/img1.jpg test.js:54:5
```

which is also exactly what I want, but this time, the ball image gets printed on the canvas, instead of img1.jpg.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you provide a working example? It would be easier for us to help you.

Comment: I added a few lines to make it work, but the example given below makes it work ! Thanks anyway !

Comment: We don't have the pictures locally and there are some variables which aren't initialized, but well, you've got your answer so.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should draw after the image is loaded. Try below code.

```
imageTest.onload = function() {

  ctx.drawImage(imageTest, 10 + (iterator + 1)*5, 10+(iterator+1)*5);

}
```

Comment: Great, it works ! I was kinda afraid this was the problem, I'll have to read some more on loading in javascript. I'm not entirely sure why it kept the value of the previous image though... Feels a bit magic now. But thanks a lot !!